# Can HTML inputs with an indeterminate state set be found via querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, queryselector

Is there a method to enable this? Or is it managed beyond the reach of CSS?

I'm thinking there's no way based on my research so far and the fact it's not rendered as an attribute on the `input`.

Comment: Inputs have a determined state, not indeterminate. Do you mean the time spent between states? Disabled, Read Only, Active, etc?

Comment: [`:indeterminate`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate) does exist.

Comment: @SebastianSimon thank you! I don't know how I overlooked that, but that's the answer and if you answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Weird that wasn't asked before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [`:indeterminate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate) pseudo class.

```js
const inp = document.querySelector("input");
inp.indeterminate = true;
```

```css
:indeterminate { outline: 5px solid red; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```